# Why is get.request is returning response 500 after a few connections?

Tags: python-3.x

I am performing a simple "page = requests.get()" with a loop to extract results from a website. After 100-150 requests, it starts returning an error 500.

I've tried two things: put a second delay between my requests (to reduce the risk that I'm causing a DOS), and I'm deleting my page variable in case the connection is being stored in memory and the server is running out of ports. However, documentation seems to say that request.get does not store active connections.

What else could it be? Why does the script stop working after a few 100 requests?

Comment: Which site/API are you querying? There might be a limitation as to how many requests per minute/hour can be made - a 1 second delay would not help there.

Comment: It is an internal application. Most likely there is some kind of rate limiter. Why would the 1 second delay not help? Should I increase to 10 seconds? When I run again, it works. However, I just want to make sure I'm not keeping active http connections. Does get.request keep active connections? I read that there's some kind of keep_alive that was implemented, but it says it doesn't apply for get.request... Any comments on that?

Comment: Best bet would be to talk to the person/team responsible for the service then. They could at least look at logfiles on their end. Regarding the 1 second: I was thinking about limitations on public APIs that sometimes have limits on requests per hour or day.

Answer (score 1):

The Error Code 500 means that **the server** has a problem handling your request. The reason for this is difficult to say if you don't control the server, but some kind of rate limiting might be the cause for this.

As per the [HTTP Specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1):

> 6.6.1.  500 Internal Server Error
>
> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the
> server    encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
> fulfilling    the request.

It's probably not a problem of your code, but some kind of rate limiting, resource shortage or other problem on the server side.

*In a perfect world the Webserver would return the [HTTP Code 429](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4) in case of rate limiting.*

Comment: I will implement a 5 second delay to ensure I don't overload the server, and a try/except condition. However, I would like to confirm: does get.request() keep a connection active? All I want is to receive the content of the webpage - no interaction necessary... Is get.request a good idea for this purpose?

Comment: Looking at the [implementation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/) of `requests.get` it appears that every call to that object creates a new `Session` object. That means there shouldn't be a persistent connection as Connection Pooling (from urllib3) seems to depend on the same session as far as I can tell. (I just had a quick glance at it, I might be wrong...)